# How to rewrite /foo , /foo/ , /foo/bar , but not /foofake?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

**I am are trying to match :**

```
http://example.com/foo

http://example.com/foo/

http://example.com/foo/bar

http://example.com/foo/bar/addditional
```

But not

```
http://example.com/foofake
```

anyone knows how to do this or does anyone have any regex for this?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this question being asked many time and SO and other places and I just have figured this nice trick out and would like to share it.

**This `RewriteRule` regex would work :**

```
RewriteRule ^foo/{0,1}(?![a-z])(.*)
```

**Further Explained :**

`foo` matches stuff begening with foo.

`/{0,1}` says that there must be zero or one trailing slashes. you may think that this will match only /foo or /foo/ , but this also matches /foofake because it also dosent have any trailing slashes after foo.

`(?![a-z])` This is the main part of this regex. This says that things within square brackets, i.e. [a-z] should not be there after foo. Beware that this will still match other characters like /foo+bar. Read on for a more complex version.

`(.*)` Says match *anything* after the trailing slash. This can also be optimised according to needs.

this is a more complex version using the same logic :

```
foo/{0,1}(?![a-zA-Z0-9`~!@$%^&*()_\-\{\}\[\]\+\=\\\|:;"'>.<,'\s])(.*)$
```

this one has all the characters on my keyboard blacklisted, so that they don't appear after /foo .

you can see the mini version in action here : http://regexr.com?33blp

and you can find the extended version in action here: http://regexr.com?33bme

I feel this method has a wide scope for improvement, so if you find any flaw or you find a way to make it awesomer, please do comment!